Computation of Norm
I am attempting an exercise from a Galois Theory problem sheet I found online. It asks:

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Let $L_1 = \mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_p) / \mathbb{Q}_p$ and let $L_2=\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt[p-1]{-p})$. Compute $N_{L_1/\mathbb{Q}_p}(L_1^\times)$ and $N_{L_2/\mathbb{Q}_p}(L_2^\times)$.

Previously in the question I have shown that $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times \cong \mathbb{Z}_p^\times \times \mathbb{Z}$, and I have shown that both extensions are totally ramified.
I have no idea how to go about computing the norm, nor do I know how to compute the $L_i^\times$ (or whether this is even necessary). Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Since the norm is multiplicative, it would help to decompose $L_i^\times$ as a direct product and see what the norm does on each factor. For that, it would be helpful to know more precisely what each factor "actually is", by which I mean e.g. in your $\mathbb Q_p^\times \simeq \mathbb Z_p^\times \times \mathbb Z$, the second factor "is actually" powers of $p$, so it suffices e.g. what a map would do on $p$, or whatever takes its place in your $L$'s.
